# Стандартный фильтр Opencart 2.3

Tags: opencart

При добавлении товара нужно прописать необходимые фильтры. Фильтры все созданы. во вкладке связи нужно добавить созданный фильтр.
когда прописываю его , по поиску подтягиваются первые 5 , а остальные не понимаю как подтянуть.
скрин прилагаю
https://prnt.sc/sjtz1d

Comment: откройте devtool вашего браузера; посмотрите, куда отправляется ajax-запрос при клике мышей на input; там есть limit, с которым из базы достаются фильтры

Comment: не могу найти где это. у меня так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле /admin/controller/catalog/filter.php

```
public function autocomplete() {
    $json = array();

    if (isset($this->request->get['filter_name'])) {
        $this->load->model('catalog/filter');

        $filter_data = array(
            'filter_name' => $this->request->get['filter_name'],
            'start'       => 0,
            'limit'       => 5
        );

        $filters = $this->model_catalog_filter->getFilters($filter_data);

        foreach ($filters as $filter) {
            $json[] = array(
                'filter_id' => $filter['filter_id'],
                'name'      => strip_tags(html_entity_decode($filter['group'] . ' &gt; ' . $filter['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))
            );
        }
    }

    $sort_order = array();

    foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
        $sort_order[$key] = $value['name'];
    }

    array_multisort($sort_order, SORT_ASC, $json);

    $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
}
```

Заменить `'limit'       => 5` на нужное количество.

Полезный трюк: в Opencart, если ввести в поле с автокомплитом %, то появится весь список.

Comment: спасибо большое